# Printing as a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a problem in python. I want to create a function to print a file from user to a new file (example.txt).

The old file is like this:

```
{'a':1,'b':2...)
```

and I want the new file like:

```
a   1,b   2(the next line)
```

But the function which I made can run but it doesn't show anything in the new file. Can someone help me please.

```
def printing(file):
    infile=open(file,'r')
    outfile=open('example.txt','w')

    dict={}
    file=dict.values()
    for key,values in file:
        print key
        print values
    outfile.write(str(dict))
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: also using the names like `dict` is not recommended

Comment: The naming convention you are using is a bit untidy.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be changing the meaning of a variable, let alone its type, throughout a program. And overriding builtins is usually not a great idea. Maybe instead use `path` and `somedict` or similar instead. Of course, using a name that actually describes what it's storing is the best.

Comment: But I can not run it, do you have the solution for this, I will change the name later.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a new empty dictionary:

```
dict={}
```

`dict` is not a good name for a variable as it shadows the built-in type `dict` and could be confusing.

This makes the name `file` point at the values in the dictionary:

```
file=dict.values()
```

`file` will be empty because `dict` was empty.

This iterates over pairs of values in `file`.

```
for key,values in file:
```

As `file` is empty nothing will happen. However if `file` weren't empty, the values in it would have to be pairs of values to unpack them into `key`, `values`.

This converts `dict` to a string and writes it to the `outfile`:

```
outfile.write(str(dict))
```

Calling `write` with a `non-str` object will call `str` on it anway, so you could just say:

```
outfile.write(dict)
```

You don't actually do anything with `infile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use re module (regular expression) to achieve what you need. Solution could be like that. Of course you can customize to fit your need. Hope this helps.

```
import re
def printing(file):
   outfile=open('example.txt','a')
   with open(file,'r') as f:
       for line in f:
           new_string = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]', ' ', line)
           outfile.write(new_string)

printing('output.txt')
```